# Create Binding for WinForms and WPF Control from the same WinForms BindingSource

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, binding, controls

**Background:** I have a Windows.Forms Database Application (a very big one, it uses Plugins for Data Sources, Renderers etc.) where I want to add an additional WPF Renderer. I tried to filter out the relevant Code parts. If more Code is needed i will post it.

**Problem:**
In my OLEDB Data Source Plugin I generate a BindingSource (System.Windows.Forms) from a **DataView**:

```
BindingSource MySource = new BindingSource { DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables[MyTable].DefaultView };
```

I can bind it to a Windows Forms Control (within a Renderer Plugin which can access the BindingSource from the Data Source Plugin):

```
System.Windows.Forms.Binding MyBinding = new System.Windows.Forms.Binding(MyProperty, MyBindingSource, MyField);
MyControl.DataBindings.Add(MyBinding);
```

When the Position of **MyBindingSource** changes, the Control gets updated.

Now I want to use the same BindingSource to update a WPF Control (within another Renderer Plugin):

```
System.Windows.Data.Binding MyWPFBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding(MyField);
MyWPFBinding.Source = MyBindingSource;
MyWPFBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
MyWPFControl.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, MyWPFBinding);
```

It works once. No matter how the Position of **MyBindingSource** changes, it always binds the values from the first Row in the DataView.

---

### **My solution** (cant post it as an answer for another 6 hours)

First, thanks to HighCore, I also moved the BindingSource from my OLEDB Plugin to my WinForms Renderer Plugin where it belongs. That also enabled my Program to create more than one View of the same DataTable!

And for WPF I did this.

Setup WPF Renderer:

```
CollectionViewSource MySource;
DataTable MyTable;
DataView MyView;

MyTable = *get table from OLEDB Plugin*;
MyView = MyTable.DefaultView;
MyView.Sort = *get table key from OLEDB Plugin* + " ASC";

ViewSource = new CollectionViewSource { Source = MyView };
ViewSource.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

Setup WPF Bindings:

```
MyBinding = new Binding(MyField);
MyBinding.Source = ViewSource.View;
MyBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

MyControl.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, MyBinding);
```

Change Event from Main Application (fired indirectly from a Row Overview Plugin to select a Dataset in all Renderers):

```
DataRowView[] row = MyView.FindRows(CurrentIndex);
ViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(row[0]);
```

I just made sure to always use the same sorting for all Renderers and use unque Keys so i always find only one row when searching.

Comment: winforms' databinding is laughable. WPF does not care about that. You should directly pass the `DataTable` to an `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` or whatever. Otherwise create a proper Data Model to bind to.

Comment: BTW, why in the world does your `OLEDB DataSource plugin` deal with winforms' stuff? You should properly separate your layers and you will not run into these issues.

Comment: I guess you are right. It updates nicely when i pass the DataTable and make changes to it. I still dont know how to select a specific row as I change the BindingSource.Position in the Main Application to select a Row. I should read up on how to correctly create a Data Model :(

Comment: again, WPF does NOT CARE about `BindingSource` (whatever that is). Create a proper ViewModel for your WPF content and manipulate that.

Comment: @HighCore sounds interesting, I think you mean the `ViewModel` should have some property `Position` so that we can change it and the row position will change accordingly? This kind of model is interesting, however I don't think people who lack experience of `WPF` can do this easily. If you know how to do it, you should add an answer (the question is also tagged as `WPF`), I'm also interested in this problem. BTW to @smoki, if you work with `WPF`, try to do the way it works, avoid the old logic in `winforms`, that would be better, I also still try to adopt this :)

Comment: I tried reading some Articles about it. But most use the built-in System of WPF/VS to create a Model. I think i cannot do that because i dont know the layout of the database before the program is run. It is a general purpose database editor where i create my own "bindings" to the underlying DataTables. i came so far that I can create a CollectionViewSource from my DataTables which i now synchronise with the current Position from the Main Application. Im currently trying to bind that ViewSource to the WPF controls. In the end i may have a lot of reading to do :)

Comment: @smoki you're on the right track.

Comment: So, my solution may be very specific but it works :)

Comment: cant post it :( it says I have to wait 6 hours... I will edit the question